# Stopping a value from writing to the screen after it's tested

Tags: powershell

I am starting to write a function that will test for a valid IP address and be built upon. I have code that works just fine, however, when the IP is valid, it will write the valid IP to the screen.  Since I will be adding onto this function where the final output will be the IP address and more, I'd like to suppress this somehow.

```
do {
   $ip=$(read-host "Enter an IP address")
   [ref]$a = $null
   $inputOk = [system.net.IPAddress]::tryparse($ip,$a)
   if ($inputOk -eq $false) {
       write-warning ("'{0}' is not a valid IP address, try again." -f $ip)
   }
} until ($inputOk)
```

Output looks like this:

```
Enter an IP address: 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
```

I'd like for it to *not* return the just entered valid ip.

Comment: Why do you use extra parenthesis around `$ip=$(read-host "Enter an IP address")`?

Comment: Oversight! thank you.

Comment: @PetSerAl That is the answer but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Matt Parenthesis are not assignment or increment/decrement, so them return value.

Comment: @PetSerAl, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
Function Test-IP {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        $IP
    )

    do {
        $IP = Read-Host "Enter an IP address"

        $Result = [System.Net.IPAddress]::TryParse($IP,[Ref]$null)

        if ($Result) {
            Write-Verbose "Valid IP found: $IP"
            <#
                Do stuff here with the valid IP
            #>
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning ("'{0}' is not a valid IP address, try again." -f $ip)
        }
    } until ($Result)
}

# See progress messages:
Test-IP -Verbose

# Without progress messages
Test-IP
```

If you create a function that has `[CmdLetBinding()]`, then you are able to use the `Verbose` switch. To show progress of a script/function, this is the way to go. If you don't want to see what is happening in the function, you just omit the `Verbose` switch.

Comment: I think the only issue was the outputting of the IP just after reading it from host, caused by the additional parenthesis.